# Group people to maximize chance of reaching the quota of each group (MS Access)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I have a random group of people who receive multiple services and need to stratify them by service received. There are 7 services, each of which has a quota in order to be representative of the whole.

There are three tables in an MS Access database.

**tblQuota(ServiceType,NumberReq)** - List of service names and quota for each.

```
ServiceType    NumbersReq
Service1       446
Service2       426
Service3       458
Service4       446
```

**tblUserService(UserID,ServiceType)** - List of users and services they receive. Many to many, each service can have many people and each person can receive many services.
**tblUser(UserID,Address,etc.)** - User contact details.

What's the best way, programatically with VBA or otherwise, to go about placing people in groups. If someone receives both a "rare" service and a "common" one, I'd obviously want to add them to the rare service that has a smaller pool of people to choose from. People who only receive one service are easy, it's the rest I'm having trouble coming up with a good algorithm for sorting.

I hope I'm making sense; I will be doing this every year with different quotas and people, so if I can get this worked out it will save a lot of time in future. Thanks.

EDIT: This is the DB I'm working with: http://db.tt/SwrOHOrd
And once a person has been assigned, they cannot be used elsewhere.

Comment: I may be reading things into your description which are not there, but you seem to be using 'service type' in two ways. Let me give you my interpretation. John has a variety of health problem (diabetes, epilepsy, high blood pressure and a rare genetic condition) each of which needs servicing. The local service teams each have a specialty but can handle any condition. By preference John will be assigned to the "Rare conditions" team but any team will do. Am I about right or do you need to revise your description?  Either way, some idea as to how you do this manually would, I believe, help.

Comment: Have you seen this: [Possible relevant question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765015/algorithm-for-fairly-assigning-tasks-to-workers-based-on-skills)

Comment: Services are things like Respite, Accomodation, Equipment and Aids etc. People can access one or many of them. I randomly chose a sample of the whole population and from that sample have to get them to fit quotas based on the overall population.

Comment: Added link to sanatized database for reference.

Comment: I am clearly missing something. Take Respite where I assume you take responsibility for someone with special needs once a week or once a month to give their regular carer a break. You have 2501 customers seeking Respite and a quote of 452.  Does this mean 2049 customers will be rejected? tblUserService has 19,676 rows but tblProportions's Numbers Req sums to about 4,000. How do these number relate? Ignoring the leading 25000000,  Customer 5 needs Residential and Therapy while customer 10 needs Residential, Day and Therapy. I would have expected a quantity field (n hours per week, for example).

Comment: Everyone on the list received their corresponding service(s) at least once in the year. There are actually over 20000 customers. I only have contact details for 14000 or so. The proportions represent a representative sample of the whole populations service use and are more than enough to statistically establish satifaction. So basically, those quotas are to make sure we get enough surveys out to make sure the services are operating as they should.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand your requirement.  I had not appreciated from the original question that you were seeking a selection of clients for satisfaction surveys.  The following is my stab at an algorithm to create that selection you require.

My SQL is rusty so I just copied Access table tbtUserService to Excel.  I sorted by client and service type to give:

**Table 1**

```
CustomerID  ServiceType
25000005    Service 1 - Hostel and Community Residential
25000005    Service 2 - Therapy
25000010    Service 1 - Hostel and Community Residential
25000010    Service 2 - Day options
25000010    Service 2 - Therapy
25000011    Service 3 - LAC
   :           :
```

I merged these records to create one row per client and renamed the service types as A to G to give:

**Table 2**

```
CustomerID  Services
25000005    AD
25000010    ACD
25000011    E
25000012    DE
25000022    AD
25000031    A
   :        :
```

I sorted that list by Services and then counted the number of each combination to give:

**Table 3**

```
Services Number  Services Number  Services Number  Services Number
A         182    AB         24    ABC         9    ABCD       34  
ABCDE       8    ABCDEF      7    ABCDEFG     1    ABCDEG      6  
ABCDF       2    ABCDG       1    ABCE        5    ABCEF       4  
ABCEFG      2    ABCEG       5    ABCF        1    ABCG        2  
ABD        17    ABDE        7    ABDEF       3    ABE         9  
ABEF        3    ABEFG       4    ABF         2    AC        185  
ACD       217    ACDE       18    ACDEF       8    ACDEFG      6  
ACDEG       2    ACDF       44    ACDFG       1    ACDG        6  
ACE        92    ACEF       12    ACEFG       6    ACEG        5  
ACF         2    ACFG        2    ACG         3    AD        254  
ADE        12    ADEF        4    ADF         4    AE         43  
AEF         8    AEFG        3    AEG         4    AFG         6  
B         143    BC         71    BCD        11    BCDE       18  
BCDEF      13    BCDEFG     19    BCDEG      11    BCDF        1  
BCDG        5    BCE       163    BCEF       47    BCEFG      16  
BCEG       18    BCF         1    BCFG        2    BCG         1  
BD          8    BDE        60    BDEF       20    BDEFG       1  
BDEG        2    BDF         1    BE        260    BEF        34  
BEFG       16    BEG        13    BF          4    BFG         1  
BG          2    C          43    CD          3    CDE       143  
CDEF       69    CDEFG      44    CDEG       26    CDF         3  
CE        489    CEF       177    CEFG       55    CEG        82  
CF          8    CG          1    D         111    DE       1726  
DEF       130    DEFG       28    DEG        13    DF          1  
E        5840    EF        312    EFG        40    EG         38  
F          17    FG          2
```

The next objective is to determine how many of each of these combinations must be selected to meet the quotas.

The required quotas were loaded from Access table tblProportions:

**Initial Table 4**

```
Service Type  Numbers Req
A              446
B              426
C              458
D              446
E             1290
F              452
G              452
```

While building one of the earlier tables, I had calculated the total number of uses of each service and added the results to table 4 to give:

```
Service Type  Numbers Req  Total uses
A              446          1285
B              426          1118
C              458          2236
D              446          3129
E             1290         10210
F              452          1197
G              452           501
```

I added a fourth column, Ratio, and sorted by that column.

**Final Table 4**

```
Service Type  Numbers Req  Total uses  Ratio
G              452           501       0.902195609
B              426          1118       0.381037567
F              452          1197       0.377610693
A              446          1285       0.347081712
C              458          2236       0.204830054
D              446          3129       0.142537552
E             1290         10210       0.126346719
```

As can be seen, 90% of clients of service G will have to be selected to meet G's quota.  So the quota for G must be considered before that of B, F, and so on.

In Table 3 (reading across and down), the first entry including service G is ABCDEFG of which there is 1 occurrence which is selected as a contribution towards G's quota.  But it is also a contribution towards the quotas of A, B, C, D, E and F.

The full complexity of the selection process is better demonstrated by considering service B.  The first entry including B is AB of which there are 24 occurrences.  Service B's ratio is 38% so we select 8 of these as a contribution towards B's quota.  This is also a contribution of 8 towards A's quota but the other 16 occurrences are not available for selection because that would cause B's quota to be exceeded.  That is, we selected 8 clients towards A's quota of 446 but have also reduced the number of clients who could contribute towards A quota by 24 from 1285.  So at every selection, we have to maintain totals of selected and still available for selection.

The quotas for each service can be met by the following selections:

**Table 5**

```
Services Slct'd  Services Slct'd  Services Slct'd  Services Slct'd
A          58    AB          8    ABC         3    ABCD       11  
ABCDE       2    ABCDEF      2    ABCDEFG     1    ABCDEG      5  
ABCDF       1    ABCDG       1    ABCE        2    ABCEF       1  
ABCEFG      2    ABCEG       5    ABCF        1    ABCG        2  
ABD         5    ABDE        2    ABDEF       1    ABE         3  
ABEF        1    ABEFG       4    ABF         1    AC          0  
ACD         0    ACDE        0    ACDEF       2    ACDEFG      5  
ACDEG       2    ACDF       10    ACDFG       1    ACDG        5  
ACE         0    ACEF        3    ACEFG       5    ACEG        5  
ACF         1    ACFG        2    ACG         3    AD        157  
ADE         0    ADEF        1    ADF         1    AE        107  
AEF         2    AEFG        3    AEG         4    AFG         5  
B          44    BC         22    BCD         3    BCDE        6  
BCDEF       4    BCDEFG     17    BCDEG      10    BCDF        1  
BCDG        4    BCE        51    BCEF       15    BCEFG      14  
BCEG       16    BCF         1    BCFG        2    BCG         1  
BD          2    BDE        19    BDEF        6    BDEFG       1  
BDEG        2    BDF         1    BE         79    BEF        11  
BEFG       14    BEG        12    BF          1    BFG         1  
BG          2    C           0    CD          0    CDE         0  
CDEF       15    CDEFG      40    CDEG       23    CDF         1  
CE          0    CEF         5    CEFG       49    CEG        74  
CF          0    CG          1    D           0    DE          0  
DEF        38    DEFG       25    DEG        12    DF          1  
E         402    EF         90    EFG        36    EG         34  
F           5    FG          2
```

There are a number of zeros in this table.  For example, no ACs, ACDs or ACDEs have been selected because the quota for service C was met by meeting the quotas for G, B and F.  Perhaps there should have been a first pass that selected one of every combination.

The final stage will be to select the 58 As in Table 5 from the 182 in Table 2.  This would be achieved by selecting about every third A.

The relationship between standard names and those used for the algorithm should perhaps have been listed earlier but is shown in Table 6.

```
A   Service 1 - Hostel and Community Residential
B   Service 1 - Supported Community Living
C   Service 2 - Day options
D   Service 2 - Therapy
E   Service 3 - LAC
F   Service 4 - Family support
G   Service 4 - Respite
```

The code used to create these results will need a little tidying but I could add it to this answer if it would be useful.